# SAS `select`...`when` based on range

Tags: select, if-statement, sas

I have blocks of code which need to be done if a fixed variable falls into a particular range, e.g.

```
IF attained_age > 84 AND attained_age < 90 then
    do;
       /* block 1*/
    end;
ELSE IF attained_age > 89 AND attained_age < 95 then
    do;
       /* block 2*/
    end;
ELSE IF attained_age > 94 then
    do;
       /* block 3*/
    end;
```

Is there a better way of writing this, with something like `SELECT...WHEN` for example? I would prefer not to list all individual values of attained age in the `WHEN` clauses though...

**UPDATE** Blocks of code involve setting a group of variables with similar names, e.g.

```
sev_alpha = &UFLIC_LM_90_94_Alpha;
sev_sigma = &UFLIC_LM_90_94_Sigma;        
sev_theta = &UFLIC_LM_90_94_Theta;
```

or

```
sev_alpha = &UFLIC_LM_95_Alpha;
sev_sigma = &UFLIC_LM_95_Sigma;
sev_theta = &UFLIC_LM_95_Theta;
```

Comment: By any chance do these blocks of code just involve setting a variable? e.g. for the 84 to 90 case, the block is something like `attained_age_cat = "atained_age_84_to_90`?  If so I have an idea I can post.

Comment: @sparc_spread yes, setting a couple variables with similar names, will update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two easy ways to do this, depending on complexities you have.

The core concept is using `symget` to get the macro variable's value.  That allows you to construct a macro variable reference in the data step, which you otherwise can't do.  I prefer this to storing the macro reference in the `proc format` as sparc_spread does, if there's a reason the value is actually in a macro variable.  (If there isn't, then skip the variable step and just store the value that is stored in the macro variable in the proc format reference.)

This allows you to compile a bunch of references easily, too; you don't have to have a separate set of formats for each variable, or anything like that, just one.  (This is where sparc_spread is going with the comments on that answer, I think.)

This can be combined with `proc format`, or it can be just done in the data step if that makes more sense - if your ranges are all groups of 5, for example, this may be easier to just do math to come up with the values.

Here's an example of both:

```
%let lim_90_94=9094;
%let lim_95=95+;
%let lim_85_89=8589;

proc format;
  value agef
  85-89='85_89'
  90-94='90_94'
  95-high='95'
  other ='NONE';
quit;


data have;
  input age;
  datalines;
  88
  92
  96
  ;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  val_a = symget(cats('lim_',put(age,agef.)));
  val_b = symget(cats('lim_',
                 floor(age/5)*5,
                 ifc(age>95,'',(cats(
                 '_',
                 ceil(age/5)*5-1)))));


  put age= val_a= val_b=;
run;
```

Comment: plusone for dynamic capabilities via `symget`.

Answer (score 3):

I can do the example for `sev_alpha`, though this can be generalized to the other two.  I unfortunately cannot test this code as I am away from my office (and SAS license) this week, but this should work OK.

There is a way of using `PROC FORMAT` that serves this type of use case. First, you write the `PROC FORMAT` like so:

```
PROC FORMAT;
    VALUE fmt_alpha
        84 <- 90 = "&UFLIC_LM_84_90_Alpha"
        90 <- 95 = "&UFLIC_LM_90_95_Alpha"
        95 - high = "&UFLIC_LM_95_Plus_Alpha"
     ;
RUN;
```

Then you can set your `sev_alpha` variable by doing this:

```
sev_alpha = PUT (attained_age, fmt_alpha.);
```

In this example, `<-` means `>=`, and `high` means the maximum numerical value.  To do the other two variables, just add two more corresponding `VALUE` blocks inside of the `PROC FORMAT`, and use similar `PUT()` calls to set the variables.

Some good documentation of using `PROC FORMAT` in this fashion can be found [in this article](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/library/nesug00/bt3001.pdf).  Basically this is my go-to approach for creating categorical variables from numeric ones, and it usually performs faster than the multiple `if/else` clauses.  Again apologies I cannot test this today but it is at the very least close to the solution.

Comment: +1, thanks. Would I be able to just construct the value of some string `range` this way, and then use this `range` to put the values of all 3 variables `call symput("UFLIC_LM_"||prefix||"_Alpha", count)` or something like that?

Comment: Yes, I think that's probably how I should have done it above.  That is, the `PROC FORMAT` and `PUT()` is for coming up with prefix only, and then you just prepend that prefix to either the word "_Alpha", "_Sigma", or "_Theta" to set each of the 3 variables.  That means only one `VALUE` block instead of three.   If I had my SAS access I would rewrite the answer above to do that, but I would need to test it first.  Anyway I think your idea is good and would work.

Comment: I like the ideas here - I don't like putting the macro reference directly in the format, but otherwise this seems useful.  Honestly you can skip the macro variables and use the format to store the various values themselves - this time in actually 3 values statements, but this avoids needing the macro variable, so no additional code ...

Comment: Thanks - I agree re the macro variables.  Mainly I was just trying to keep as much of the original code as possible, but in the end you're right, they can go.